# Get Value of Div after append function

Tags: jquery

All,
I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).on('change','.found_other_vendor',function(){
if(checked){
    alert("it was checked");
    if($("#other_liked_vendors").val()!=""){
        alert("second_one");
        $.post(ajaxurl, { clicked_id: clicked_id, action: action }, function(results){
            $("#other_liked_vendors").append(", " + results);
        });
        $("#other_liked_vendors")
    }else{
        alert("first_one");
        $.post(ajaxurl, { clicked_id: clicked_id, action: action }, function(results){
            $("#other_liked_vendors").html(results);
        });
    }
}
}
```

For some reason it always says that my first if statement for:

```
if($("#other_liked_vendors").val()!="")
```

Is always coming up false even after I've put data in my div with the html. Any idea why it isn't recognize a value in my div even after I put data in it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can only use `.val()` on form elements. For everything else use either `.text()` or `.html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to write

```
$("#other_liked_vendors").html()
```

as it seems like `"#other_liked_vendors"` is a `div`. You can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only with form elements. You have to use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for elements like div.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` returns the value of a form element.
You want `.text()` or `.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem you're using `val()` correctly. Documentation for `val()`:

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns null.